# mousenter and mouse effect not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/malleswar/F2smc/1/)

When I mouseenter on Span1 , a blue bar should appear below the Span1 (same for Span2 and Span3)

But even I mouseenter on Span1 or Span2 or Span3 , blue bar appears only under Span2.

**CSS**

```
div.demo {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
div.demo div {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
}
.under {
    width:100px;
    height:2px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin:0px auto;
    display:block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="demo">
    <div id='span1'>Span 1</div>
    <div id='span2'>Span 2</div>
    <div id='span3'>Span 3</div>
</div>
<div class="demo">
    <div><span id='Span1'></span></div>
    <div><span id='Span2'></span></div>
    <div><span id='Span3'></span></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#span1').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#Span1').addClass('under');
    });
    $('#span2').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#Span2').addClass('under');
    });
    $('#span3').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#Span3').addClass('under');
    });
    $('#span1').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#Span1').removeClass('under');
    });
    $('#span2').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#Span2').removeClass('under');
    });
    $('#span3').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#Span3').removeClass('under');
    });

});
```

Comment: strange according to firebug none of the 3 ever gets the class `under`, not in my league i thinksisss.

Comment: mouseenter and mouseleave do not work on many browsers.http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html

Answer (score 2):

You have no width on the cells before the hover

### Working JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/F2smc/5/

```
div.demo div {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    width: 33%;   // <<< Added this
}
```

Basically the other 2 cells are zero width so the second row collapses to something very narrow in the middle so it looks like it is only under option 2.

### Better example: http://jsfiddle.net/F2smc/29/

You can get the same effect, without specifying an exact % width, by simply adding this CSS instead for the spans (so they do not collapse within their parent divs):

```
div.demo span
{
    width:100%;
}
```

If you put unique colors on the divs it will become really obvious what is going on. 100% on the div does not mean the divs will use it like in a table. Basically any change that applies a width to the underlining divs/spans will work. Suggest you use Chrome in F12 debug mode to view this type of work as it clearly shows the original elements were all 0 width.

*PS. Is really is a bad idea to use ids that vary only in case*

### On a separate note:

You would not normally hardwire events for each different id in JQuery when they all do roughly the same thing. If you change your ids to be really unique (not just by case) you can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu').hover(function () {
        $('#' + this.id + '-l').addClass('under');
    }, function () {
        $('span').removeClass('under');
    });
});
```

Which takes the id of the current hovered item, appends something unique then updates the matching item by id.

### Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F2smc/30/

*That should clean things up while retaining your original structure.*

Comment: I'll change the ids, and if there are more Spans (i.e span4, span 5 etc), I have to change the width: 33% to what so ever?

Comment: So long as they have a width, like the row above, it will work... I know this will get flak, but, given the layout you are attempting, you may want to use a real table so the columns auto-size to the data row.

Comment: @Lonely: I have Updated the answer with a cleaner version so that you do not need to specify a percentage for different numbers of elements. Apply a 100% size to the spans instead to avoid the collapse.

Answer (score 0):

For testing i have given text-decoration,you replace that with background-color..

**HTML**

```
<div class="demo">
    <div id='one' class="hover">Span 1</div>
    <div id='two' class="hover">Span 2</div>
    <div id='three' class="hover">Span 3</div>
</div>
<div class="demo">
    <div><span id='Span1'></span></div>
    <div><span id='Span2'></span></div>
    <div><span id='Span3'></span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.demo {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
div.demo div {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
}
.under {
    width:auto;
    height:1px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    margin:0px auto;
    display:block;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hover').hover(function(){
     var id=$(this).attr("id");
        $('#'+id).addClass('under');
    },function(){
$('.hover').removeClass('under');
});

});
```

Comment: Your example is doing `$('#' + this.id).addClass('under')` which is a long-winded way to do the same as `$(this).addClass('under')`... Why make things harder? The asker was using a second row to display the bar, not the actual items.

Comment: *Great (if somewhat optimistic) username by the way :)*

Answer (score 0):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/F2smc/10/)**

Try this

I have editted your html and css

```
<div class="demo">
    <div id='span1'>Span 1</div>
    <div id='span2'>Span 2</div>
    <div id='span3'>Span 3</div>
</div>
<div class="demo">
    <span id='Span1'></span>
    <span id='Span2'></span>
   <span id='Span3'></span>
</div>
```

and add this to your css

```
div.demo span {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100px;
}
```

### **or**

Try this

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/F2smc/11/)**

without changing any html and css

just add  `width:100px;` to

```
div.demo div {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;    
}
```

Hope this helps,thank you